# In R, how can I randomly choose two out three names 500 times, with balanced selections?

Tags: r, random, database-design

I know I can use complete_ra from the randomizr package to randomly and equally allocate to one of three "arms" (in this case "arms" are just names of people)

```
library(randomizr)
set.seed(100)
names <- complete_ra(N = 500, num_arms = 3) 
#each "arm" is chosen ~167 times

#Now put the names in
library(plyr)
df <- transform(df,
            names=revalue(names,c("T1"="Luis", "T2"="Conor","T3"="Dafydd")))
```

But what I need is to actually assign the 500 samples to a randomly chosen two of the three names. So I need my dataset to be:

```
ID#  Name1   Name2
1   Conor    Luis
2   Conor    Dafydd
3   Luis     Dafydd
...
500 Conor    Luis
```

and at the end I need each of the 3 to still be chosen an equal amount.

A workaround is since there's 3 names, that means there's 3 combinations too, so I could simply replace Conor with "Conor and Luis", Luis with "Luis and Dafydd", and Dafydd with "Conor and Dafydd"...but I'm sure there's a more eloquent way that would allow for other combinations (like choosing 2 out of 4 names). Also I don't like the workaround because currently each name can show up 8 times in a row for example, which means we would have an exact pair 8 times in a row. I think a more eloquent method of randomly choosing 2 out of the 3 names would result in fewer "in a row" cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to select n elements from a list (without replacement here) would be `sample`. Here a simple way to create 500 such samples and transform the result into a `data.frame`:

```r
set.seed(100)
names <- c("Luis", "Conor", "Dafydd")
samples <- lapply(1:500, function(x) sample(names, 2))
head(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(samples), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
#>       V1     V2
#> 1   Luis Dafydd
#> 2  Conor   Luis
#> 3  Conor   Luis
#> 4 Dafydd   Luis
#> 5  Conor   Luis
#> 6  Conor Dafydd
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun approach with `randomizr` and `tidyverse`. It treats each person as a block of two observations, then uses `pivot_wider` to reshape the data

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(randomizr)

tibble(
  person_id = rep(1:500, each = 2),
  name = rep(c("Name1", "Name2"), 500),
  assignment = block_ra(
    blocks = person_id,
    conditions = c("Luis", "Conor", "Dafydd")
  )
) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = assignment)
#> # A tibble: 500 x 3
#>    person_id Name1  Name2 
#>        <int> <fct>  <fct> 
#>  1         1 Luis   Dafydd
#>  2         2 Conor  Luis  
#>  3         3 Dafydd Luis  
#>  4         4 Dafydd Conor 
#>  5         5 Conor  Dafydd
#>  6         6 Luis   Dafydd
#>  7         7 Dafydd Luis  
#>  8         8 Conor  Luis  
#>  9         9 Conor  Luis  
#> 10        10 Dafydd Conor 
#> # … with 490 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>